# Python Pyramid not rendering JSON correctly

Tags: python, json, pyramid, mongoengine

I am using MongoEngine's `to_json` method on an object I wish to render in a json-rendered Pyarmid page.  I've done lots of json rendering in Pyramid, but not with MongoEngine.  MongoEngine's `to_json` method simple calls `json_util.dumps`.  It all works fine in Python. The problem is that when Pyramid renders the page, it is rendered like this:

```
{
  "0": "\"",
  "1": "{",
  "2": "\\",
  "3": "\"",
  "4": "_",  etc...
```

However, the json dump looks ok in Python, before it is rendered:

```
'{"_id": {"$oid": "4ebca43ccc7a67085b000000"}, "created": {"$date": 1346419407715}, "modified": {"$date": 1403757381829}, "modified_by": {"$oid": "4ebca43ccc7a67085b000000"}, "email":  etc...
```

As has been suggested in the comments, it seems like the json is being jsonified more than once, but I can't figure out where.

I pick up the `User` object from the database and attach it every request:

```
def get_user(request):
    return User.objects(id=ObjectId(authenticated_userid(request))).first()

config.add_request_method(get_user, 'user', reify=True)
```

I return the user as per request:

```
@view_config(route_name='api.user', permission='authenticated', renderer='json')
def user_vc(request):
    response = request.response
    _id = request.matchdict['id']
    if _id == 'session':
        user = request.user
        if not user:
            response.status = 403
            return response
        else:
            print user  # user object as expected (not json)
            return user
```

I have a custom adapter to handle the `User` object:

```
# custom json adapters
custom_json = JSON()

def user_adapter(obj, request):
    print obj.to_json()  # the json looks ok here
    return obj.to_json()
custom_json.add_adapter(User, user_adapter)

config.add_renderer('json', custom_json)
```

I am not doing any other jsonification myself, apart from the adapter above.  So what is??  Any help would be great.

Comment: Very clearly you are jsonifying your data many times. The "pyramid renders the page like this" looks like Javascript iterating over a string object would behave.

Comment: In any case you need to add the relevant code in your question, as per guidelines!

Comment: Thank you @AnttiHaapala.  I have added relevant code, as per your good suggestion.

Comment: Pyramid already has a builtin JSON renderer. Is there a reason for defining your own custom one? Your view is already configured to use the ``json`` renderer, so skip defining your custom renderer and simply return a dictionary. Pyramid takes care of rendering the dictionary to JSON.

Comment: The adapter should return a python data structure, not a string.

Comment: @PedroRomano Of course.  But it is much more efficient to create a custom renderer for custom objects which Pyramid does not natively decode rather than have to convert the object every time it is returned.  I guess that's why the ability to create custom renderers exists in Pyramid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a comment by @AnttiHappala above, I found the problem.  MongoEngine's `to_json` method converts objects to a jsonified string.  However, Pyramid needs a json data structure.  So, to fix it, I added the following function to my custom renderer:

```
def render_to_json(obj):
        return json.loads(obj.to_json())

    def user_adapter(obj, request):
        return render_to_json(obj)
    custom_json.add_adapter(User, user_adapter)
```

I can now add a custom renderer for my other MongoEngine objects and return them natively.